# Powershell XML Encoding HTML

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, encoding

I have a little problem with powershell.
I try to randomly create passwords for active directory users during installation via a script, but when I open my XML file I see an encode type html (& etc).

The generated password
Luk/&ftD+pB8^pJ
The XML file
Luk/&ftD+pB8^pJ

I tried changing the encoding type without effect.

I would like to know how to save the passwords as they are.

For the moment I redid a pass on the xml file with a replace to modify the characters.

Thanks

`code`

```
$xmlsettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$xmlsettings.Indent = $true
$xmlsettings.IndentChars = "    "
#$xmlsettings.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode - UTF-8
$XmlWriter = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create("C:\Users\AdminSec\Desktop\00 - Home\Users.xml", $xmlsettings)

$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument()
$xmlWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='style.xsl'")
$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("ADDS")
    $xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Users") # <-- Start <Object>
    $i = 0
    while($i -ne 250)
    {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Web'
        $Password = [System.Web.Security.Membership]::GeneratePassword(15, 1)
        $xmlWriter.WriteElementString("TEST",$Password)
        $i++
    }
    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # <-- End <Object>
$xmlWriter.WriteEndElement() # <-- End <Root> 
$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlsettings.Encoding
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

`code`

Answer (score 0):

the posted example of the string (Luk/&ftD+pB8^pJ) is identical. But I think I know what you mean, in XML the following chars have to be escaped:

```
"   &quot;
'   &apos;
<   &lt;
>   &gt;
&   &amp;
```

But thats not an issue, once you read those values (assuming you load the XML as XML) you get the original string back.